# Sql server 2012 log file growth of cdc enbled db

Tags: sql-server, log, change-data-capture

I have CDC enabled on a SQL Server 2012 database that is a primary DB in transactional replication and the primary in a availability group. The log file is a little over 95 GB, a historic high. I have the `cdc._cleanup` job running every 5 minutes. We have a weekly full backup, nightly differentials, and transaction logs that run every 15 minutes. The default retention time for CDC is still set for 72 hours.

I am not able to shrink the log. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does "not able to" mean? What does `log_reuse_wait_desc` say in `sys.databases`? Are you shrinking the log file not knowing whether it will just increase again? Just because it's a historic high does not mean it's not the new normal.

Comment: If log_reuse_wait_desc says REPLICATION, take a look at sys.dm_cdc_log_scan_sessions to see if CDC is caught up.  The capture job is running, right?